# In Datagridview c# edit mode how to keep cursor in current cell when cursor in last or first position of text

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

In Datagridview c# edit mode how to keep cursor in current cell when cursor in last or first position of text. currently when cursor in edit mode and it is in last or first position then if I press left or right arrow key it is moving to another cell. I would like to keep it in current cell as like as excel.but currently it is moving to another cell in Datagridview edit mode

In Datagridview c# edit mode how to keep cursor in current cell when cursor in last or first position of text. currently when cursor in edit mode and it is in last or first position then if I press left or right arrow key it is moving to another cell. I would like to keep it in current cell as like as excel.